# Checking for CustomizeApplication fails in unit test

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am checking for `CustomizeApplication` like so:

```
 List<UserPermissionAccess> permissions = [SELECT Id, PermissionsCustomizeApplication FROM UserPermissionAccess];
        if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
            UserPermissionAccess permission = permissions.get(0);
            if (!permission.PermissionsCustomizeApplication) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Then, I run my test in Apex:

```
    @isTest
    static void myTest() {
        Test.startTest();
        System.assert(MyClass.myMethod());
        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

This is always returning false because my `permissions` is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can change your code to:

```
return 0 < [SELECT COUNT() FROM UserPermissionAccess WHERE PermissionsCustomizeApplication = true];
```

This gives you an immediate boolean result and 100% code coverage.

As far as testing, I think there may be a bug? This code works in live code, but not in a unit test, even with System.runAs, which makes me think there's some sort of limitation on this object, but I don't see anything in the documentation.